# Can one determine your Windows license key by accessing your computer

Tags: identity, license-key, honeypot

I want to set up a honeypot type trap to catch out and secretly record a tech support scam firm that conned my Grandparents out of a lot of money for a non issue on their computer. Like many such scam firms, they occasionally change their web address and phone numbers and are partially based in India.

I was thinking about running Windows 7 inside a virtual machine and using a SOCKS proxy for the VM's internet connection to hide my true Static IP.

I am then planning to make a video about the scammers and put it on YouTube.

The thing is though, I am doubting  whether that I can legally record a conversation in a covert manner and then put it on YT. (In UK)

What I really want to know is whether the scammers will be able to get my private license key,  or any other identifiable information from the VM when they have control of it? Also does them having the product ID (including them going through Microsoft) put my license/copy of Windows in jeopardy?

I ideally want to bring them to justice and spread the word about them so that they get closed down. In other words, I want to get my own back on them.

**Side Note: If this forum is not appropriate for this question, where would be?**

Regards: Elliott

Comment: This does not belong here.   Perhaps it belongs on Super-User or Server-Fault.

Comment: Don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they can easily know that you run on a VM. Just with simple command about your hardware. But, I am sure they will not check if it is a honey pot.I dont know how you are planning to record them. I dont believe that you can record something interesting visually.The first step for them is to have a rootkit on your pc. After that is just about command line. There will be nothing good to record visually other that text line in your honey pot software. And You dont know when the attack you will come. Your Vm must be up all the time and the Ip and Mac address the same. Like the others say dont waste your time.No one in history a been put in jail for hacking a honey pot.